# Android AdMobview Cant Show on Device?

Tags: android

I have addmobview and its works fine in emulator but when i test in device it doesn't show.

Layout::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/admoblayout"
    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

LogCat is ::

```
02-17 20:37:39.367: I/Ads(15146): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=13&u_sd=0.75&u_w=240&slotname=a14f3df0f8ed46f&msid=com.votingcard.vcdemocrat&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4&isu=3023B13C2FDE783814C10FF9F2E7A3A2&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=4.0.4.android.com.votingcard.vcdemocrat&hl=en&u_h=320&testing=1&u_so=p&u_audio=1&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-330&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=3&caps=SdkAdmobApiForAds&jsv=3", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
02-17 20:37:40.992: I/Ads(15146): onFailedToReceiveAd(No ad to show.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to a low [fill rate.](http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/07/admob-fill-rate.html) Your fill rate will increase as your app gets more traffic. Have you set up your device as a test device so you can at least receive test ads?

Edit: To add a test device, you can do the following:

```
//set up your ad request
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

//emulator ready for testing
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
//your device ready for testing
request.addTestDevice("deviceid");
```

The [Google Code](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#addtestdevice) site has a lot of usefull info on AdMob integration

Comment: How can i set Device as a test Device and Can you elaborate your answer I cant understand....

Comment: Np sir. You can always check your fill rate percentage on the AdMob site, under your Sites & Apps.

Comment: It's actually your device id. Check out this article http://webhole.net/2011/12/02/android-sdk-tutorial-get-admob-test-device-id/